# RestSharp jsonException: error. How do I deserialize?

Tags: c#, .net, api, restsharp

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public double discountPercentage { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public int stock { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public List<string> images { get; set; }
}
```

}

--

```
 public class ProductClient : IProductClient
    {
        private readonly RestClient _client;
        private readonly string _url;

        public ProductClient()
        {
            _url = "https://dummyjson.com/products";
            var options = new RestClientOptions(_url);
            _client = new RestClient(options);
        }


   Task<List<ProductViewModel>> GetAllProduct();


 public async Task<List<ProductViewModel>> GetAllProduct()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest();
        //request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        var response = await _client.GetAsync<List<ProductViewModel>>(request);
        
        return response;
    }
```

ProductsController:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAllProduct();
            return Ok(response);
        }
```

**JsonException:** The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DummyShop.Service.ViewModel.ProductViewModel]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.

I get this error. No matter what I did, I couldn't get over this problem. Likewise, the data I will need to send a post request belongs to DummyJson.

Comment: It’s a bit hard to help without showing us you’re response that you’re trying to deserialize.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean but I am trying to connect DummyJson fake api to my own api project. I wrote the error I got above. Since it is Json type, I get an error when making a get request in my api, I couldn't solve it for about 1 day

Comment: The `response` should be valid JSON. Check that first. Then check that it ties up with the type you're trying to deserialise into. We can't comment on either of these as you haven't shown any sample JSON that the `_client` returns, nor have you shown the `ProductViewModel`. If you add both of those to your question, we are more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: I made an edit, is that enough?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I made an edit

Comment: No, where’s the json?

Comment: https://dummyjson.com/products  Is this?

Comment: @KaanYılmazer Great, now we see the class, but where's some sample JSON? That is vital. Your error is serialising JSON, which only actually involves the JSON and the class you're using for serilisation. All the rest of your code can be removed, but without some sample JSON, no-one will be able to help you

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't fully understand the example you want from me. I posted all my classes here What do you mean by Json example? Isn't it the data in DummyJson? I can't understand, unfortunately, I've been dealing with this for 1.2 days, my brain is not in place anymore. @AvrohomYisroel

Comment: @KaanYılmazerDon't worry, we've all been there! I didn't realise that www.dummyjson.com was a real site, I thought it was something you made up to avoid including the real source of your JSON. Either way, you should always include include sample data in your question. In this case, you should have included a sample of the JSON from that site. Now I see the JSON, I'll take another look.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think that the dummy json data could not be understood and I was trying to understand the questions where is the Json :) I will also make Post Put and Delete requests after the Get request, but I think I can do the remaining requests if I handle the Get request.
I transferred this fake api to my own api application. Then I will connect it to my Mvc web application and perform crud operations.

Comment: @KaanYılmazer See the answer I just posted. I think it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to deserialise only **part** of the JSON that you get. If you look carefully, the incoming JSON has four properties, `products` which is the array of products you want, as well as three integer propeties at the end.

You can do what you want by adding an extra class...

```cs
oublic class Data {
  public ProductViewModel[] Products { get; set; }
  public int Total { get; set; }
  public int Skip { get; set; }
  public int Limit { get; set; }
}
```

...and then your deserialisation will work fine.

I copied the JSON from the URL you included, and successfully deserialised it as follows...

```cs
Data data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json, 
     new JsonSerializerOptions {PropertyNameCaseInsensitive=true});
```

This gave the all the data in the JSON. To access the products, you just look at `data.Products`.

Note that I added the case insensitivity part as your properties are all lower-case, and by default (depending on the environment you are deserialising in), the deserialiser expects capitalised property names.

Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me a lot now I am trying to adapt this to my own code
Data data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json <-
I couldn't understand the json in this part, I wonder where it comes from

Comment: public async Task<List<RootViewModel>> GetAllProduct()
        {
            var request = new RestRequest();
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(request);
            RootViewModel data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootViewModel>(response,
            new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            return data;
        }

i try like this but i get an error the code is red

Comment: Do it in two separate stages, first call the URL to get the JSON as a string. Once you have that, pass it to the deserialiser like I showed. That will help you work out where the problem is. The code I posted works fine, so it may be that there's something else going on. If so, start a new question.

Comment: Sorry, just seen the first comment. `json` is simply the string data you get from that URL. For simplicity, I just loaded that page in my browser and copied all the JSON into a string variable named `json`. That way I was able to look at the deserialisation without worrying about the code to get the JSON in the first place.

Comment: public async Task<List<RootViewModel>> GetAllProduct()
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("products");
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(request);
            RootViewModel data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<RootViewModel>>(response);
            return response;
        }

Comment: where am i wrong in this code snippet i wonder i understood your method thank you but i couldn't fit the code

Comment: As I said to you last night, split this into two parts. First check that what you're getting back from the service is the JSON you expect. If it is, then my code should deserialise it. If what you get back doesn't match what you see when you go to the URL, then the problem is with the code you use to download the data, and so should be posted in a new question (without the deserialisation part)

Comment: Actually, I just spotted your error. You are still trying to deserilaise the JSON as a `List<RootViewModel>`, even though the JSON won't fit into that. Even if it did, you are then trying to assign the deserialised object to something of type `RootViewModel` which isn't even consistent. Read my answer again, and spot that your basic problem is that the JSON you pull from the URL needs to be deserialised into an object that has a **property** of type `List<RootViewModel>`